# Choking Game: what is a "locked doors" warning sign?

Tags: expressions

Today, I heard about the so called "Choking Game" which is allegedly a game played by irresponsible kids where you restrict blood flow to your brain in order to, later on, produce the sensation of having the blood rush back into it. Basically, you ask someone to choke you.

I eventually saw this image talking about it:

[image]

In the "Warning signs" section, what is **Locked doors**?

Comment: That the kid has locked themselves in their room.

Comment: Oh... that simple? I thought it would be some unappropriate slang for a body sign... Thanks for the help and sorry for such a simple question!

Comment: I've never understood why kids would voluntarily choke themselves. So disturbing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"locked doors", refers to **a kid's bedroom door**. It is one of the signs that a child can be indulging in such a dangerous game, especially if associated with any of the other warning signs. I had never heard of such a game before and, as an M.D., consider it extremely dangerous - **death or permanent sequelae can ensue**. Parents should be warned, though I believe most children wouldn't try it.

Comment: Thank you. Toryan made a comment first, so I upvoted his comment and will accept your answer as well. Agree 100% about the dangerous part and the possibility of permanent damage...